# cython prange not so fast than single thread

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, cython

I just wrote a trivial program to test how `cython`'s `prange` performs, and here is the code:

```
from cython.parallel import prange
import numpy as np

def func(int r, int c):
  cdef:
    double[:,:] a = np.arange(r*c, dtype=np.double).reshape(r,c)
    double total = 0
    int i, j

  for i in prange(r, nogil=True, schedule='static', chunksize=1):
    for j in range(c):
      total += a[i,j]

  return total
```

On Mac Book pro, with `OMP_NUM_THREADS=3`, the above code takes almost 18 sec for `(r,c) = (10000, 100000)`, and with single thread, it takes about 21 sec.

Why there is so little performance boost? Am I using this `prange` correctly?

Comment: Turn off `boundschecking` first, experiment with different schedule types and chunksizes  and see what you get. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193851/cython-prange-slower-for-4-threads-then-with-range/33204449#33204449) question. You are performing `sum-reduction` and compilers do a great job of optimizing such loops in serial mode and with `OpenMP` pragmas, the resulted assembly code may not be that optimal in this case.

Comment: @romeric, tried, results are no better at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you timed how long it takes just to allocate `a`? A 10000 x 100000 float64 array takes up 8GB of memory.

```
a = np.ones((10000, 100000), np.double)
```

takes over six seconds on my laptop with 16GB of RAM. If you don't have 8GB free then you'll hit the swap and it will take a *lot* longer. Since `func` spends almost all of its time just allocating `a`, parallelizing your outer `for` loop can therefore only gain you a small fractional improvement on the total runtime.

To demonstrate this, I have modified your function to accept `a` as an input. In `tmp.pyx`:

```
#cython: boundscheck=False, wraparound=False, initializedcheck=False

from cython.parallel cimport prange

def serial(double[:, :] a):
    cdef:
        double total = 0
        int i, j
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            total += a[i, j]
    return total

def parallel(double[:, :] a):
    cdef:
        double total = 0
        int i, j
    for i in prange(a.shape[0], nogil=True, schedule='static', chunksize=1):
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            total += a[i, j]
    return total
```

For example:

```
In [1]: import tmp

In [2]: r, c = 10000, 100000

In [3]: a = np.random.randn(r, c)   # this takes ~6.75 sec

In [4]: %timeit tmp.serial(a)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.25 s per loop

In [5]: %timeit tmp.parallel(a)
1 loops, best of 3: 450 ms per loop
```

Parallelizing the function gave about a 2.8x speed-up* on my laptop with 4 cores, but this is only a small fraction of the time taken to allocate `a`.

The lesson here is to always profile your code to understand where it spends its most of its time before you dive into optimizations.

---

* You could do a little better by passing larger chunks of `a` to each worker process, e.g. by increasing `chunksize` or using `schedule='guided'`

Comment: Oh, yes, I neglect the allocation part, you're right, thanks so much, lesson learnt.